# Generatos of non-abelian Galois group of order 8.

Tags: galois-theory

Trying to find generators of Galois group of K:Q where K is the splitting field for $x^4 - 6x^2 -2$. I have the four roots (plus minus $\alpha$ and plus minus $\beta$) and K is generated by $\alpha$ and the product $\alpha\beta=i\sqrt2 $. I have found all the elements and the order, however, I am stuck on trying to find the generators of the group? My next task is to list all the subgroups and find the subfields. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $Gal(K/\mathbb Q)$ must be the dihedral group of order 8 from Kaplansky's Theorem. Therefore, it must be generated by some $\rho$ and $\tau$ where $\tau^2 = 1$, $\rho^4 = 1$ and $\rho\tau = \tau\rho^{-1}$.

Comment: I have τ2 that fixes alfa and sends αβ to -αβ. However, the only generator of order 4 I can think of is such that sends α to β=(i(2)^(1/2)/α) and sends αβ to 1/αβ. Can't figure out how else to get rid of the i(2)^(1/2). However, 1/αβ is not a root.

Comment: Also, the action of the group on the four zeros is faithful. So the group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$. Because the order is 8, it is a Sylow 2-subgroup, and hence isomorphic to $D_4$. Nothing wrong with your approach either :-)